# Backfill new column with values based on foreign key

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to RDS and am looking for help in updating a new column with ascending values based on a FK.

Can I and should I be doing this as a sequence of SQL commands that calculates my business logic on server-side?  This seems plausible to me because the business logic (ascending based on FK) seems straightforward.  Or should I be running client code to read rows, calculate business logic on client, then write back to db?

Would I be using `function` to achieve this?

Specifically, I am adding a new column `ordinal` to my `devices` table.  The default value is `0` and I would like to update that column to instead count ascending for a particular user.  So, if there are 3 rows for a given user in `devices`, those 3 rows would respectively have `ordinal` set to `1`, `2`, and `3`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE devices (
    id character varying PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id uuid REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
ALTER TABLE "devices" ADD COLUMN "ordinal" integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
```

I am running `PostgreSQL 9.6.6`

Thank you

---

I have made some headway on a function.  For the update step when I set ordinal, is there any way to set the column through the context of the current iteration?  I.e. something like `current.ordinal = new_val`?

Inspiration: [Looping Through Query Results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION backfill_device_ordinal(uuid) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    device RECORD;
    ordinal INTEGER;
BEGIN
    ordinal = 1;
    FOR device IN SELECT * FROM devices WHERE user_id = $1 LOOP
        -- Now "device" has one record from "devices"
        RAISE NOTICE 'Updating device ordinal: user=%, ordinal=%...', device.user_id, device.seat_ordinal;

        /* is this optimal? */
        EXECUTE format('UPDATE devices SET seat_ordinal = %I WHERE user_id = "%s" AND id = "%s"', ordinal, device.user_id, device.id);

        ordinal = ordinal + 1;
    END LOOP;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Done updating device ordinal.';
    RETURN ordinal;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * from get_next_device('00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [correlated subquery](https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/aw_pgsql_book/node80.html#SECTION001522000000000000000) to update all rows at once.
To determine the `ordinal` value, just count how many other rows for the same user come before this one when you sort them:

```
UPDATE devices
SET seat_ordinal = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM devices AS d2
                    WHERE d2.user_id  = devices.user_id
                      AND d2.id      <= devices.id);    -- some arbitrary sort order
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which works.  In terms of performance, can we consider each `COUNT(*)` to be only `O{M}` (where `M` is number of `devices`) because we are sorting against an indexed UUID?  That is, it's not a scan operation.

Comment: Ask the database to EXPLAIN it to you.